# Am I slow or is it normal for all projects to take so long and longer than expected?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to this. I have been learning java for a few months and I am working on my first project, myself.

What confuses me is that I write a few lines, run it, sometimes it works, a lot of times it doesnt. Then I have to google it, find a solution, incorporate it. Then I try to write more code, sometimes it works and often I have to repeat the whole process , or ask here at stackoverflow.

Now probably because i am new , with practice I won't need to look up things as often, HOWEVER, as my skills get better, the projects I take on will get harder as well,so I am guessing that I will STILL have to keep looking things up. Like I learnt how to send data over TCP/IP, then I had to look up how to encrypt it, then how to encrypt with strong encryption, then store that data in a derby datase , each time I have to continually look things up.

**So the question:**

Part 1:Does this process ever end? Surely it must, otherwise how do software projects get finished. Programmers couldn't be looking things up all the time? Do I just need loads and loads of coding hours?
Part 2:It always seems to take longer than I anticipate. If I am using the GUI editor to design a form and think I can do it in two days ( as an example) something ALWAYS goes wrong and it takes 2-3 times as long. If I am so lousy, I won't even be able to hold a job, I'd be fired in 3 days :(

Any help from experienced people greatly appreciated.thanks

Le Prince De Dhump

Comment: It will take less time the 2nd or 3rd time you do it.

Comment: Somewhat offtopic. Read the FAQ at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ to see if that site could help.

Comment: it'll take less time as you become more experienced. you get to understand what the error messages mean, and can track them down without having to google them. System.out.println is your best friend as a beginner trying to debug stuff

Comment: There'll always be things you know and things you don't, as in any field of expertise. I would say that is even worse in this field since it's **very** extense and there're always new things coming up. If you want to *not* have to always look up things on an specific topic, you can always read a book about it, practice a lot and get really good at it; but nobody can't be an expert on every aspect of software developing/programming :/

Comment: It's not about how good you are, but about how much progress you are making. If you keep up the progress, you'll find yourself at ease tackling ever harder problems. And big projects are nothing but several smaller projects. At a certain point you start levelling off and finding out new things becomes an easy and predictable process.

Answer (score 2):

As you get more experienced, you will have to look things up less and less. However, I can tell you that you will never stop looking things up altogether. I've been using Java for about 8 years now and still use Google to look up code snippets and answers to questions all the time. There's no shame in it, it's just part of being a programmer.

Comment: But doesn't having to look up things constantly drastically slow down coding speed? Or is that the norm? thx

Comment: I'm not saying it'll be a constant thing, when you work on similar things over and over you won't have to look it up as much. But that's just how it is at first, and even the most experienced developers still have to look things up from time to time.

Comment: thank you very much for your time and advice :) that soothes my bruised soul

Answer (score 2):

**Part1:** I write programs for about 25 jars and still use google or search in books to find solutions  [Its often faster than come up with something new of your own]. More practice and better knowledge of the libraries, data structures and algorithms reduce the amount of searching on the web.

**Part2:** It is a common problem in software development to underestimate the time needed for the implementation. You need a lot of practice and review what was the reason it took longer than expected. It seams that software developers tend to  blank out all the little problems that will eat so much time while implementation.

My advice: Split your problem in little peaces and estimate the needed time separately. If possible compare the problems to one you have solved in the past and remember how many time they took. And at the end of the project review which estimations where totally wrong and try to figure out what was the reason. That helps for future estimations.

Out there are so many books which try to help you to solve the time estimation problem. Reading some of them may also give clues what the pitfalls are.

Comment: thank you very much for your inpute... really appreciate it :) that will help me not jump off a cliff

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a more general issue regarding with the concept of skill acquisition (so perhaps more suitable for "the workplace" site).

There are two good bools about the subject, "Mastery" by Robert Greene and "Outliers" by Malcolm Gladwell, about this subject and the 10,000 hours necessary needed to acquire a disciple.

A short answer: this is the normal: these things that you are doing have not yet been "wired" to your brain and that takes time and attempts. After some time doing those tasks, you will be able to "remember" faster, or do them on subconsciously. Additionally you will be able to build associations, so that your mind will be able to recognise more patterns (or differences) etc. Each thing that gets "in" your head will be accomplished with less effort therefore you will be able to think deeper and achieve more at the same time.